# Finder window pops up every time Time Machine makes a backup

Tags: macos, finder, time-machine, backup, time-capsule

I have configured a shiny new Time Capsule a few days ago. It runs firmware 7.7.1 and my Mac is on 10.8.4.

The Time Capsule works perfectly so far, except that every time Time Machine makes a backup, a Finder window showing the contents of the “Time Machine Backups” volume pops up (see screenshot). This gets especially annoying with hourly backups. I backed up with an external hard drive before and did not have that issue as far as i know. How can I stop Time Machine/Finder from opening up that window every time?

[image]

Comment: My guess is that the .DS_Store file was modified by looking at that folder in Finder when a backup was happening. Are you familiar / comfortable with typing into terminal some commands to delete files? You could try deleting that one file (being careful to not delete anything else from the backups) - but it's just a guess since this isn't normally what happens for backups.

Comment: Yes, i am comfortable using the command line. Deleting the `.DS_Store` files from both the Volume and the Sparsebundle did not fix the issue, however.

Comment: I also tried setting the folder to open to a nonexistent folder with the `bless` command [as detailed here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2009121606541533), but to no avail.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://simon.heimlicher.com/articles/2009/01/10/time-machine-readonly i will certainly give it a shot!

Comment: @bmike i have noticed that the Sparsebundle is mounted read-only. The default behavior of Finder is to open such devices in a new window. Is it ok that the device is mounted read-only or should it be writeable instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by running

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages auto-open-rw-root -bool false
```

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/584237/make-time-machine-stop-opening-a-new-window-when-backing-up